# gvisGeoMap + shiny + Rpresentation

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, googlevis

I'm trying to create interactive slides using the new R presentations + shiny + gvisGeoMap

This is what I have right now:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Name1"
date: "06/25/2014"
output: ioslides_presentation
runtime: shiny
---


## Slide with Interactive Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(googleVis))
inputPanel(
  selectInput("select", 
        label = "Select G1 or G2",
        choices = list("G1", "G2"),
        selected = "G1")
)

renderPlot({
  if(input$select=="G1"){
    G1 <- gvisGeoMap(Exports, locationvar='Country', numvar='Profit',
                 options=list(dataMode="regions")) 

    plot(G1)
  }else{
    G2 <- gvisGeoMap(CityPopularity, locationvar='City', numvar='Popularity',
                 options=list(region='US', height=350, 
                              dataMode='markers',
                              colors='[0xFF8747, 0xFFB581, 0xc06000]')) 
    plot(G2)
  }

})
```
````

I can create the html but the map do not print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`googleVis` plots use the `renderGvis` function.  You need to pass the `googleVis` object and not call `plot`.
The `renderGvis` needs to be assigned to output and called using `htmlOutput`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Name1"
date: "06/25/2014"
output: ioslides_presentation
runtime: shiny
---


## Slide with Interactive Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(googleVis))
inputPanel(
  selectInput("select", 
        label = "Select G1 or G2",
        choices = list("G1", "G2"),
        selected = "G1")
)

output$test <- renderGvis({
  if(input$select=="G1"){
    G1 <- gvisGeoMap(Exports, locationvar='Country', numvar='Profit',
                 options=list(dataMode="regions", width="100%")
                 , chartid = 'mychart') 

    G1
  }else{
    G2 <- gvisGeoMap(CityPopularity, locationvar='City', numvar='Popularity',
                 options=list(region='US', height=350, width="100%", 
                              dataMode='markers',
                              colors='[0xFF8747, 0xFFB581, 0xc06000]'
                              ), chartid = 'mychart') 
    G2
  }

})
htmlOutput("test")

```
````

[image]
[image]

Comment: bonus question: Is there a way to make the map auto resize to avoid having so much white space?

Comment: Declare `width="100%"` as an option